# What causes the error that says "Could not find the Service Class" for a service wrapped by WinRun4j

Tags: java, windows, service, wrapper, winrun4j

I have the following error when running a jar wrapped by WinRun4J:

```
[info] Module Name: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\src\com\service\wrapper\ServiceWrapper.exe
[info] Module INI: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\src\com\service\wrapper\ServiceWrapper.ini
[info] Module Dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\src\com\service\wrapper\
[info] INI Dir: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\src\com\service\wrapper\
[info] Working directory set to: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\src\com\service\wrapper
[info] Configured vm.location:
[info] Found VM: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
[info] Expanding Classpath: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\build\classes\
[info] Expanding Classpath: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\dist\lib\WinRun4J.jar
[info] Generated Classpath: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\dist\lib\WinRun4J.jar
[info] VM Args:
[info] vmarg.0=-Djava.class.path=C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 
6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\dist\lib\WinRun4J.jar
[info] Registering natives for Native class
[info] Registering natives for FFI class
 [err] Could not find service class
 [err] Failed to initialise service: 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/service/wrapper/ServiceWrapper/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.service.wrapper.ServiceWrapper.
class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

This is the `service.ini` I wrote for this wrapper ...

```
service.class=com.service.wrapper.ServiceWrapper
service.id=Service_Simulation
service.name=Windows_Java_Wrapped_Service
service.description=This is an Example for Java Service
service.startup="boot"
main.class=com.service.wrapper.ServiceWrapper
classpath.1=C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\build\classes\
classpath.2=C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NETBEANS 6.9.1\Desktop_apps\Test2\dist\lib\WinRun4J.jar
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using two incompatible parameters in your service.ini.
You must introduce either `service.class` or `main.class`,  but not both.

If you want your .exe to be executed always as a service, you must use `service.class` and register it in the Windows Service Manager, like so:

```
executable.exe --WinRun4J:RegisterService
```

If you want it to be a normal application, you must use `main.class` and call it normally.

If you want to execute it in both ways, you have to fall back to some roundabout like the one [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/winrun4j/discussion/693148/thread/61068827#cd2d). CopyPasting from the link:

> I have the same requirement, for what will be around 10 or so
>   services. Each must also be available to support people for command
>   line execution, passing optional parameters for a "single run" mode of
>   operation.
>
> I have simply created a pair of ini files for each copy of the service
>   executable that represents each service. Each service ini file is
>   identical to it's command line partner apart from the head that
>   follows, with the service/command line parts commented as appropriate:

```
working.directory=. 
service.class=com.xgs.cfs.services.ServiceControl 
service.id=service_id service.name=Windows Service Name 
service.description=Service Description
#command line app configuration
#main.class=com.xgs.cfs.services.ServiceControl
#console.title=process name
#singleinstance=process
```

> The service is run from the Windows SCM and the command line launch
>   uses the following command from a batch file, stored in a more user
>   friendly location:

```
%deploymentroot%/svc_bin/service_name_svc.exe --WinRun4J:ExecuteINI %deploymentroot%/svc_bin/service_name_exe.ini
```

> (`%deploymentroot%` is an environment variable used throughout the
>   project to help manage paths.)
>
> The above batch command is the key here, as it tells the winrun4j
>   wrapper to use a different inin file to the default executable name.
>   The service will pickup the default name (service_name_svc.ini) from
>   the service binaries folder.
>
> The class com.xgs.cfs.services.ServiceControl it written so that it
>   has no dependencies on the service control callbacks for operation
>   (i.e. it starts automatically, and all required normal shut down is
>   accomplished via Java shut down hooks making the whole lot as ctrl-c
>   safe as is possible.). You could simply change the startup class if
>   required though I have found it unnecessary.